# access database from multiple kubernetes pods

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

1. 

I have 2 applications in 2 pods as well as a Postgres db deployed using a helm chart. The one application writes to the database and the other one uses only select operation for read. Is there any case where I can get a race condition?

2)

Is there any way to have both read and write to the above database from 2 different pods hosting different applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If only one of the two applications will be writing to the database, there should not be any risk of a race condition.
2. Yes, you can define two pods for the two applications and have them both connect to the database. You could create a [helm subchart](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) for each application, define the Postgresql connection details in a ConfigMap in the parent chart, and then have each subchart's deployment [load the ConfigMap as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) so your applications can connect to the database.